# What about having a tag on Oxidation-reduction

Tags: discussion, tags

Red-ox reaction is quite a common reaction, which most branches of chemists will encounter. Hence what about having a tag on "Red-Ox" / "reduction-oxidation".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend the tag 'redox' as this abbreviation is virtually ubiquitous.